# AutoMapper and conditional mapping to null

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to create mapping like this:

- if the source property has it's Id == 0, set the destination property to null
- if the source property has it's Id != 0, map this property using default configuration

For example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ItemViewModel, Item>()
    .ForMember(x => x.DestinationArticle, o => o.SetNullIfSourceHasIdZero(x => x.SourceArticle));
```

The DestinationArticle and SourceArticle properties are of implementing:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    long Id { get; set }
}
```

My current solution is this:

```
.ForMember(x => x.DestinationArticle, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.SourceArticle != null && x.SourceArticle.Id != 0 ? Mapper.Map<Article>(x.SourceArticle) : null))
```

which is not so good and not generic.

So, is there any way to create, mentioned before, SetNullIfSourceHasIdZero extension method or something, which could make my life easier?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines..

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ItemViewModel, Item>()
    .ForMember(x => x.DestinationArticle, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<SetNullIfSourceHasIdZero>());

public class SetNullIfSourceHasIdZero : ValueResolver<ItemViewModel, DestinationArticle>
{
     protected override DestinationArticle ResolveCore(ItemViewModel item)
     {
        // logic here            
     }
}
```

Comment: It means that I have to create my SetNullIfSourceHasIdZero's classes for all my view-models with that kind of mapping scenario...

Comment: How about this:
`public class SetNullIfSourceHasIdZero<T, U> : ValueResolver<T, U>
{
    protected override U ResolveCore(T source)
    {
        /* logic */
    }
}`

and then use it like this:

`opt => opt.ResolveUsing<SetNullIfSourceHasIdZero<ItemViewModel, DestinationArticle>>()`